# Fetch data from 3 different tables with SQLAlchemy or SQLModel

Tags: api, sqlalchemy, orm, fastapi, sqlmodel

I want to fetch data from 3 tables with SQLAlchemy or SQLModel. For example lets say that my tables are the following:

```
class A(SQLModel, table=true):
    id: int
    title: str

class B(SQLModel, table=true):
    id: int
    a_id: foreign_key("a.id")
    name: str
 
class C(SQLModel, table=true):
    id: int
    b_id: foreign_key("b.id")
    text: str
```

The response that I want to have is the following:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "This is A table",
        "b": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "This is B table",
                "c":[
                   {
                        "id":1,
                        "text": "My text from c" 
                   }               
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I am trying with selectinload but doesn't work

```
query = (
        select(A)
        .where(A.id == a_id)
        .options(
            selectinload(A.b).joinedload(
                B.c
            )
        )
    )

    try:
        response = (await session.exec(query)).one()
    except NoResultFound:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Data not found")
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried these models with newer version of sqlalchemy (not sqlmodel) it works as shown in this example (sqlalchemy=1.4.39)

```
class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(length=100))

    b = relationship("B", backref="a")

class B(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'b'

   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   name = Column(String(length=100))

   a_id = Column(ForeignKey('a.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))

   c = relationship("C", backref="b")

class C(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'c'

   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   text = Column(String(length=100))

   b_id = Column(ForeignKey('b.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
```

Query:

```
stmt = select(A).options(selectinload(A.b).selectinload(B.c))
resp = await session.execute(query)
return resp.scalars().all()
```

(Prepare pydantic model related to this query)
schema.py

```
class CResp(BaseModel):
    id: int
    text: str

class BResp(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    c: List[CResp]

class AResp(BaseModel):
    id: int
    title: str
    b: List[BResp]
```

views.py

```
@app.get("/", response_model=List[AResp])
async def index(session=Depends(get_session)):
    query = select(A).options(selectinload(A.b).selectinload(B.c))
    resp = await session.execute(query)
    return resp.scalars().all()
```

If you want to use this query with sqlmodel, you can try some other versions of sqlalchemy as mentioned here ([SQLModel error: "AttributeError: 'Team' object has no attribute 'heroes'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72866418/sqlmodel-error-attributeerror-team-object-has-no-attribute-heroes)), sqlmodel has some problems with SQLalchemy 1.4.36+ versions

Comment: Hey Rasim, thank you very much for your answer and sorry for my late response! I know about the problems sqlmodel has with SQLAlchemy. I tried your solution and it works. The problem was that I didn't use correct the second ```.selectinload(B.c)```.